# Can't send stream to the server in setTimeout

Tags: node.js, stream, request, fs, multer

I've been trying to upload an image file stream (using createReadStream) to the server (using Multer).

I'm using request module.

When a request is sent first time, everything works fine. The server receives the stream, processes it and save it to a file.

After few seconds (using setTimeout), the same file stream is sent again to the server, but neither the multer runs nor the client receives any response. It keeps waiting.

I found that file stream when the stream is used. But, I've set autoClose to false. Still no luck.

I have also tried saving the stream in a buffer, and then uploading the buffer to the server but multer is unable to process it, I get an empty req.files object.

If you can help or give me a direction, I'll appreciate. I've been trying to fix this for more than a week.

```
let formData = {};
formData.imageFile = fs.createReadStream('./file.jpg', { autoClose: false });

request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });

setTimeout(() => {

    request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData}, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });
  }, 10000);
```

The first request works perfectly. The second does not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will work, effectively we're re-opening the stream.

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

function getFileStream(fileName) {
    return fs.createReadStream(fileName, { autoClose: true });
}

let formData = { imageFile: getFileStream('./file.jpg') };

console.log('Uploading..');
request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Uploading again..');
    formData = { imageFile: getFileStream('./file.jpg') };
    request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData}, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });
  }, 10000);
```

You can also just load the file into memory, avoiding the use of streams entirely:

```
const request = require('request');
const fs = require('fs');

let formData = {
    imageFile: {
        value:  fs.readFileSync('./file.jpg'),
        options: {
          filename: 'file.jpg',
          contentType: 'image/jpeg'
        }
    }
};

console.log('Uploading..');
request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData }, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });

setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('Uploading again..');
    request.post({ url: config.uploadURL, formData}, (err, response, body) => {
      if (err) {
        return console.error('upload failed:', err);
      }
      console.log('Received response');
    });
  }, 10000);
```

Comment: Your code is also not working when integrated with my code. It however works perfectly if run alone. There is something which is messing with everything.

Thanks (I'll mark the answer as completed soon)

Comment: I can't edit my above comment. Your both code is working perfectly fine. There were some useless piece of code. Thanks for saving my time. The second option is more better.